# Call Vue Slot by Dynamic name

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a component called `TableContainer` with the following dynamically named slots

```js
// ...
<td class="...">
    <slot :name="'statuses-' + item.id" />
</td>

<td class="">
    <slot :name="'actions-' + item.id" />
</td>
//...
```

I want to call them from the parent component as follows:

```html
<TableContainer :data="people">

  <template v-for="person in people" v-slot:statuses-{person.id}>
     {{ person.status }}  
  </template>

</TableContainer>
```

This is not working at all.
But when I put it like below, it is working, and painting status on the first row.

```html
<TableContainer :data="people">

  <template v-for="person in people" v-slot:statuses-1>
     {{ person.status }}  
  </template>

</TableContainer>
```

Note I have switched `v-slot:statuses-{person.id}` with `v-slot:statuses-1`.

How do I call the slot while providing a dynamic name.

> I am using Vue 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the syntax for [dynamic slot names](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#dynamic-slot-names). Try

```html
  <template v-for="person in people" v-slot:[`statuses-${person.id}`]>
     {{ person.status }}  
  </template>
```

Comment: I saw how to define them but not reference them. You're a life saver.